# How to find documents by value which match either a document's attribute or an array's element

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection with the following document:

```
{ "_id" : "DzQuhq22NhQm5waCm", "title" : "Test", "users" : [ "wCxEmesi2M73dLze4" ], "userId" : "htMZEZTMxsQXq6sRD", "createdAt" : ISODate("2015-10-05T12:09:34.852Z") }
```

The attribute `users` is an array which contains also `userId`s.

Now I want to find this document if my value is either within the `users` array or matches the `userId`. So, this document should be returned if my value is `htMZEZTMxsQXq6sRD` or `wCxEmesi2M73dLze4`.

I tried the following:
`db.test.find({userId: val}, {users: {$in: val});` but this does not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
db.getCollection('TESTCOLLECTION').find({$or:[{'userId':'htMZEZTMxsQXq6sRD '},{'users':'wCxEmesi2M73dLze4'}]})
```